# Why PHP function returns TRUE?

Tags: php

Why does my `isset()` function return true when the value from the select option in the HTML form is set to `=""` which I was expecting to be `NULL` and the `isset()` function should return FALSE ?

This is the HTML select option:

```
<select name="filler">
 <option value="">Select Transfer</option>
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Inside this isset function i've added a JS alert and this alert is triggered

```
 if(isset($_POST['filler'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("filler item in post");
    </script>
   ....other PHP code runs here....

 }
```

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. The `<select>` value is set to `""`, an empty string, and an empty string is not null. Your variable **is** set.

Comment: Use `empty()` instead. `isset()`. **The isset function in PHP is used to determine whether a variable is set or not. A variable is considered as a set variable if it has a value other than NULL. **

Comment: Thank you ! :) this is down to my PHP learning error

Comment: You could just `print_r($_POST);` to see what got submitted

Comment: thanks @brombeer i will consider this in future rather than switching to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [isset()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_isset.asp) function checks whether a variable is set, which means that it has to be declared and is not NULL.

"" is empty string which is not null.

I think you are after  [empty()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_empty.asp)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

isset() is used to check if the variable is set with the value or not

and after isset you can also check empty

Empty() is used to check if a given variable is empty or not. isset() returns true when the variable is not null whereas Empty() returns true if the variable is an empty string.